# REACT - Supabase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, supabase

I am Running this piece of code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';

const supabase = createClient("https://<project>.supabase.co", '<anon-key>');

const GetBalance = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);

    async function getData() {
        const { udata } = await supabase.from("balances").select();
        setData(udata);
    }

    return (
        <ul>
            {data.map(transactions => (
                <li key={transactions.balance}>{transactions.balance}</li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}

export default GetBalance;
```

it responds with 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').'
I have disables RLS on supabase and the table does include data and is not empty.

Is this a syntactical error in my code? or have I configured my supabase project incorrectly?
I have searched online and disables RLS however it has done nothing

I was trying to connect to my database on supabase but it would connect but not display data. I then disables RLS and it spits out this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that if i change the line

`const { udata } = await supabase.from("balances").select();`

to

`const { data: udata } = await supabase.from("balances").select();`

it would work as it was a variable issue with the nameing

Comment: This is correct because the `.select()` function returns an object containing `{ data, error }` so you having it set to `{ udata }` would not work. The change you made would work as you are aliasing `data` to `udata`.

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to `console.log` 'data' to see if you are getting any. Seems like the 'data' is undefined. You could also try writing this:

```
{data?.map((transactions) => (
    <li key={transactions.balance}>{transactions.balance}</li>
))}
```

Also, I believe you intentionally replaced the actual project id and key values in the line below with  and , but just making sure:

`const supabase = createClient("https://<project>.supabase.co", '<anon-key>');`. Of course, these should be values you get from your project dashboard.

Comment: I have tried the question mark response but it responds with noting and therefore suppresses the error.

Comment: I console.log the error and it replied with Array(0) (btw i know my credentials just don't want to display publicly here). Could it be part of my useEffect and useState hooks? I am not sure at this point